# Export com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg module in java module application

Tags: java, java-module

info look like :

```
module ir.mehritco.megnatis.faststonecapture {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.controlsfx.controls;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires camera.framework;
    requires javafx.swing;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j.core;
    requires org.json;
    requires org.xerial.sqlitejdbc;
    requires com.ibm.icu;
    requires camera.binding;
    requires com.sun.jna;
    requires org.apache.commons.imaging;
    requires org.apache.commons.io;

    opens ir.mehritco.megnatis.faststonecapture.gui to javafx.fxml;
    exports ir.mehritco.megnatis.faststonecapture.gui;
    exports ir.mehritco.megnatis.faststonecapture;
    opens ir.mehritco.megnatis.faststonecapture to
            javafx.fxml, org.apache.logging.log4j,
            org.apache.logging.log4j.core, org.json,
            org.xerial.sqlitejdbc, java.desktop;
    exports ir.mehritco.megnatis.faststonecapture.canon;
    opens ir.mehritco.megnatis.faststonecapture.opencv to javafx.graphics, javafx.fxml;

}
```

The Problem is, I need use class JPEGMetadata that is in JDK 17 under the com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg and java.desktop so I added The JPEGMetadata and As you can see The requires java.desktop; is present but I get error :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class ir.mehritco.megnatis.faststonecapture.GraphicsPath (in module ir.mehritco.megnatis.faststonecapture) cannot access class com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGMetadata (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg to module ir.mehritco.megnatis.faststonecapture
    at ir.mehritco.megnatis.faststonecapture/ir.mehritco.megnatis.faststonecapture.GraphicsPath.lambda$exportImageToFile$2(GraphicsPath.java:606)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Idk what can I do to resolve it.

The part of Code that need this class:

```
new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    App.logger.debug("Going to create Export With File : " + fileName);
                    BufferedImage scaleUpImage = scale(bufferedImage, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB,
                            (int) convertMMToPx(theWidthOfBondClipInMM()), (int) convertMMToPx(theHeightOfBondClipInMM())
                            , convertMMToPx(theWidthOfBondClipInMM()) / bufferedImage.getWidth()
                            , convertMMToPx(theHeightOfBondClipInMM()) / bufferedImage.getHeight());

                    Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(ext);
                    while (writers.hasNext()) {
                        ImageWriter writer = writers.next();
                        ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
                        ImageTypeSpecifier typeSpecifier = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                        IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(typeSpecifier, writeParam);
                        if (metadata.isReadOnly() || !metadata.isStandardMetadataFormatSupported()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        JPEGMetadata jpegMetadata = (JPEGMetadata) metadata;
                        try {
                            IIOMetadataNode horiz = new IIOMetadataNode("HorizontalPixelSize");
                            horiz.setAttribute("value", Double.toString(getDpi()));
                            IIOMetadataNode vert = new IIOMetadataNode("VerticalPixelSize");
                            vert.setAttribute("value", Double.toString(getDpi()));
                            IIOMetadataNode dim = new IIOMetadataNode("Dimension");
                            dim.appendChild(horiz);
                            dim.appendChild(vert);
                            jpegMetadata.mergeTree("Dimension", dim);

                            BufferedImage removeAlphaChannelAndScaleUpImage = removeAlphaChannel(scaleUpImage);
                            writer.write(jpegMetadata, new IIOImage(removeAlphaChannelAndScaleUpImage, null, jpegMetadata), writeParam);
                            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                            try {
                                desktop.open(file);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                App.logger.fatal("Ops! look at this fatal error in opening the file explorer: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                            return;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                } finally {
                    loadingBarForMes.setVisible(false);
                }
            }).start();
```

Comment: Why do you need to use classes in a psckage that should not be used by applications?

Comment: I use Java.desktop and I need it because of create metadata for image that created by ImageIO .

Comment: @aled do i misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes.  You do.  You shouldn't >>need<< to use an internal class.  Perhaps you should show us the relevant code so that we can figure out why you are using that class, and suggest alternatives?

Comment: @aled added extra code.

Comment: Why are you casting the `IIOMetadata` to a `JPEGMetadata`?  Given what you do with it, it seems unnecessary.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is that line going to exception and I want add some metadata into buffered image.

Comment: I need add dpi of H and W of image into JPEG metadata.I know its broken code but my Problem is added the class into my application.

Comment: Use a third party Library.

Comment: I want to know Why I cant Use This class ! if my project isnt Module base I can use it.  Its impossible or just Idk how to use it?

Comment: Have you tried specifying `--add-exports`?

Comment: how can I use? @Naman

Comment: You don’t need to use the JPEGMetadata class in your code.  `metadata.mergeTree` is exactly the same as jpegMetadata.mergeTree.